# Sum as many columns as indicated in other sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, worksheet

I am creating an excel workbook with finances for a company. In this workbook is a sheet with the income statement and a sheet with parameters.

In the sheet with parameters is a cell with the number of quarters how long a service contract of a product of the company is expected to last.

In the sheet with the income statement I want to sum as much cells as the number in the parameters sheet.

e.g. "Parameter"-sheet cell B7 has the number 4. Now in the "Income statement"-sheet I want the sum from cells C8 to 4 columns to the right (because Parameters!B7 = 4). But if I change the number in Parameters to 5 it has to take automatically 5 columns to the right in the Income statement.

I have tried with changing my Excel to R1C1, but I have no clue how to create this. With or (if possible) without VB.

It has to be something like this:
`=SUM(R8C3:R8C[+Paramaters!R7C2])`

Comment: This is possible using the Indirect() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.  The first would be offset.  Your offset formula is based off this format.

```
OFFSET(REFERENCE CELL, NUMBER OF ROWS TO MOVE, NUMBER OF COLUMNS TO MOVE, HOW MANY ROWS TO RETURN FROM THE NEW POINT, HOW MANY COLUMNS TO RETURN FROM THE NEW POINT)
```

Positive moves your down or to the right.  Negative values move your left or up.

So in your case you would be looking at something like:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($C8,0,0,1,'Parameters'!B7))
```

Now I did not lock the 8 in case you were planning on copying down and wanted a new row for each line you copied down and did not want C8 to always be the same reference point.  However there are ways around that and keep $C$8 if you prefer.

Now having said that, if you are just using offset a few times, by all means go ahead it wont slow things down.  However if you are using it quite frequently, it will slow things down as it is a volatile function that will recalculate anytime any information is changed on the worksheet.

Now to get around that we have options!

You could also go with the INDEX option.  The index option, since it returns a cell address behind the scenes, could be used as follows:

```
=SUM(C8:INDEX(8:8,COLUMN(C8)+'Parameters'!B7))
```

Comment: SORRY you would need to change back from R1C1 style or you will need to adjust the cell references accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Didn't got the first thing working, but the INDEX option did the trick.